# Python 2.6: Class inside a Class?

Tags: python, class

Hey everyone, my problem is that im trying to figure out how to get a class INSIDE another class.

What I am doing is I have a class for an Airplane with all its statistics as to how fast it can fly, how far it can go, fuel consumption, and so on. Then I have a Flight Class which is all the details about the flight: Distance, starting location and time, ending location and time, duration, and so on.

But I realized that each airplane has multiple flights, so why not put all the flight data into the airplane class? Although how do i put a class INTO another class so i can call something like this:

```
Player1.Airplane5.Flight6.duration = 5 hours
```

Ive somewhat done it with the airplane class, but when i go to save the information (listing everything out into a text document), all it gives me is the Hex location of the data and not the actual strings.

```
class Player (object):#Player Class to define variables
    '''Player class to define variables'''

    def __init__ (self, stock = 0, bank = 200000, fuel = 0, total_flights = 0, total_pax = 0):
        self.stock = stock
        self.bank = bank
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.total_flights = total_flights
        self.total_pax = total_pax
        self.Airplanes = Airplanes
        self.flight_list = flight_list
```

Is there a way to put a class inside a class? or will i need to make one super Player class which handles all the information which im using other classes for?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I think you are confusing objects and classes. A class inside a class looks like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    class Bar(object):
        pass

>>> foo = Foo()
>>> bar = Foo.Bar()
```

But it doesn't look to me like that's what you want. Perhaps you are after a simple containment hierarchy:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, ... airplanes ...) # airplanes is a list of Airplane objects
        ...
        self.airplanes = airplanes
        ...

class Airplane(object):
    def __init__(self, ... flights ...) # flights is a list of Flight objects
        ...
        self.flights = flights
        ...

class Flight(object):
    def __init__(self, ... duration ...)
        ...
        self.duration = duration
        ...
```

Then you can build and use the objects thus:

```
player = Player(...[
    Airplane(... [
        Flight(...duration=10...),
        Flight(...duration=15...),
        ] ... ),
    Airplane(...[
        Flight(...duration=20...),
        Flight(...duration=11...),
        Flight(...duration=25...),
        ]...),
    ])

player.airplanes[5].flights[6].duration = 5
```

Answer (score 29):

It sounds like you are talking about *aggregation*. Each instance of your `player` class can contain zero or more instances of `Airplane`, which, in turn, can contain zero or more instances of `Flight`. You can implement this in Python using the built-in `list` type to save you naming variables with numbers.

```
class Flight(object):

    def __init__(self, duration):
        self.duration = duration


class Airplane(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.flights = []

    def add_flight(self, duration):
        self.flights.append(Flight(duration))


class Player(object):

    def __init__ (self, stock = 0, bank = 200000, fuel = 0, total_pax = 0):
        self.stock = stock
        self.bank = bank
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.total_pax = total_pax
        self.airplanes = []


    def add_planes(self):
        self.airplanes.append(Airplane())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    player = Player()
    player.add_planes()
    player.airplanes[0].add_flight(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Second:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

class First:
    def SecondClass(self, data):
        return Second(data)

FirstClass = First()
SecondClass = FirstClass.SecondClass('now you see me')
print SecondClass.data
```

Comment: need some functionality description.